# Unexpected performance degradation in unpickled set in python

Tags: python

Set operations of a separately pickled objects are significantly slower than set operations of normal objects, or jointly pickled object.

```py
import random
import timeit
import pickle

data = set(tuple([n]*100) for n in range(2000))
subset = set(random.sample(data, k=1000))

data2 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(data))
subset2 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(subset))

data3, subset3 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps([data, subset]))

print(timeit.timeit(lambda: data & subset, number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: data2 & subset2, number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: data3 & subset3, number=1000))
```

stdout:

```
0.037282757000184574
1.339586072999964
0.038100944000007075
```

Almost 3000% difference. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The culprit was that separately pickled objects have different memory address, while in other 2 cases the objects have same memory address.

Credits to @hexnewbie from LiberaChat `#python` channel.

```
len({id(x) for x in data} & {id(x) for x in subset})  # 1000
len({id(x) for x in data2} & {id(x) for x in subset2})  # 0
len({id(x) for x in data3} & {id(x) for x in subset3})  # 1000
```